# Alert when a file/directory upload has failed

Tags: network-monitoring, zabbix

I am using Ubuntu and needed to know if there is any way to produce an alert when a File copy/upload operation has failed.
The scenario is as such:

I have file xxxxx on my computer/server. However, everyday file xxxxx is being copied to another server in a remote location. Is there any solution that will notify me in case the file has not been successfully transferred. I am using Zabbix Monitoring tool. I have already tried diff function, but I do not want to compare two files, I just need to be alerted if file/directory has not reach destination. Please help it is very urgent.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your situation can you check the exit code of the application using to perform the copy?  You can get this value in bash via $?.  So for instance if you were using scp

```
# Successful copy
$ scp myFile remote.example.com:.
$ echo $?
0

# Unsuccessful copy
$ scp myFile remote.example.com:.
$ echo $?
1
```

0 indicated success, non 0 values indicate error such as if the copy is terminated or the target dir doesn't exist.

If you needed instead to confirm the files are identical you could use the md5sum command (or md5 on some OSs such as OS X)

```
$ echo "This is a test" > myFile
$ scp myFile remote.example.com:.
$ md5sum myFile # Local value
ff22941336956098ae9a564289d1bf1b  myFile
$ ssh remote.example.com "md5sum myFile"  # Remote value
ff22941336956098ae9a564289d1bf1b  myFile
```

All of this should be easy enough to add to whatever script you're using to perform the backup.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to zabbix but Ill try to help.

How do you copy files from one server to another?
If you can access to those procedures which do copy files you can try call zabbix_sender to
deliver message to Zabbix server of fail copying in case that you have exception during copy of files

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manpages/zabbix_sender